# Moving mongo field within document if it exists

Tags: mongodb

We are refactoring a mongo database, and I'd like to pull the value for one field, and place it into a hash in array in another field. Here is how the data looks in the document before:

```
basecampURL: "https://basecamp.com/123/",
trackingSystems: [
    {
        type: "github",
        url: "https://github.com/org/repo/issues/"
    }
]
```

And here is what I'm hoping to accomplish:

```
trackingSystems: [
    {
        type: "basecamp",
        url: "https://basecamp.com/123/"
    },
    {
        type: "github",
        url: "https://github.com/org/repo/issues/"
    }
]
```

I've tried a few variations of this code, and where I'm running into an issue is when referencing the found variable for basecampURL, all of the examples on [MongoDB Update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-a-field-in-a-document) are using a string.

```
db.projects.update( 
    { basecampURL: '.+' }, 
    { $push: 
        { trackingSystems: 
            { 
                type: 'basecamp',
                url: basecampURL // this isn't valid, also tried $.basecampURL
            }
        },
      $unset: 
        { basecampURL: '.+' }
    },
    { multi: true}
)
```

It seems like I'm not finding how to reference the found item's properties, but I've been wondering if I need to do store the found variable prior to the update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this using a javascript function similar to this:

```
db.coll.find({basecampURL : {$exists : true}}).forEach(
    function(doc) {
        var bc = {};
        bc.type = "basecamp";
        bc.url = doc.basecampURL;
        doc.trackingSystems.push(bc);
        // deletes the previous value
        delete doc.basecampURL;
        db.coll.save(doc);
   }
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks @orid. Was scratching my head on that one. Updated to also remove the original basecampURL field.

Answer (score 5):

**Do not use a cursor if you can avoid it. They are extremely slow**

Now there is mongo $rename:

`db.COLLECTION_NAME.updateMany( {/*filter if you want*/}, { $rename: { "oldFieldName": "newFieldName" } } )`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Comment: He is moving the value to an array... I don't think renaming solves that. Also, it looks like Mongo does not have a way to access a doc from within an update(), so it seems that iterating all the entities and modifying from javascript logic is the way to go.